# Background size not updating when I update CSS file

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a web UI that currently has a blue banner. However, when I try to modify its size in the CSS chunk below, it doesn't update. Before, in the code below, `background-size` was set to `cover`, but I need the height of the banner to shrink.

```css
#header {
      background-color: #04f;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flex;
      display: flex;
      -moz-align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      -moz-justify-content: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -moz-flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 8em 0 6em 0;
      background-size: 20px 20px;
      background-position: center top;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      cursor: default;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Author Script by SANDERS</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css?version=1" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<header id="header" class="alt">
<div class="inner">
 <h1>Sanders Author Script</h1>
 <p>A free author formatting script by Stephan J. Sanders</p>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide your html code

Comment: Check whether the other attributes are being updated.

Comment: is your example code missing `background-image` property?

Comment: @WillD: I took the background image away on purpose, because I didn't want an image in the banner for now.

Comment: @Animan: The other attributes (such as `background-color`) do indeed update when I change them.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache when you reload?

Comment: @JessicaWard: yes, I do a hard refresh.

Comment: Does it work if you delete stuff from your css file? Are you sure you are editing/loading the file you are editing?

Comment: @Huangism: Yes I am sure because when I edit other attributes in that CSS chunk, the page updates. It just doesn't update the background-size for some reason.

Comment: What do you finally want to achieve?

Comment: Do you know how to inspect? Something is probably overriding it, can you attach the full css file? there is probably another rule in there which overrides it. Try this, delete everything from the file except for the header part, it will most likely work then, you just need to find what's overriding it. Easiest way is to inspect the element

Comment: @Anima: it's stated in the question description...

Answer (score 0):

You can add height property to the css ID.

```
#header {
  background-color: #04f;
  height : 500px;
  width : 100%;
```

}

Comment: add some description